# Who makes polyimide stiffeners for FPCs?

Tags: connector, fpc

I have an FPC that is 0.075mm thick and I am trying to find a FPC zero insertion force connector to fit it. The smallest FPC connector I can find on Mouser or Digikey accepts FPC thickness down to 0.18mm ([here](http://au.mouser.com/Search/ProductDetail.aspx?R=FH12-8S-0.5SH(55)virtualkey64550000virtualkey798-FH128S05SH55)).

As a result I think I will need to use an FPC stiffener to thicken the FPC to fit the connector. Page 15 of the aforementioned connector's [datasheet](http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/185/FH12_catalog-939276.pdf) outline the construction of the FPC including the stiffener and from which I have picked up key terms to search. I have had little experience using stiffeners however upon searching key terms (FPC stiffener, polyimide stiffener, zif connector stiffener etc) have not been able to find manufacturers of them, only materials such as polyimide film on Alibaba.

My question is if I am designing a cable and require a stiffener, who normally manufactures these stiffeners: the connector company (Molex/Hirose/Harwin), the FPC manufacturer (contractor) or the end FPC purchaser and product designer (myself) prior to use in the end product?

Comment: Thanks tcrosley, I'm not actually looking for a place to purchase/specific products, rather who in the process of creating a cable is usually expected to make a stiffener - myself, the connector manufacturer or the contractor manufacturing the design of the FPC.

Comment: The FPC maker takes care of this. Just give them a drawing and money and they will do the rest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am purchasing flex PCBs from two different manufacturers. In both cases, the manufacturer bonds the required stiffeners in the proper locations as part of the manufacturing process.

Our flex PCBs have different thicknesses of stiffner in various locations. This was not a problem.